# Session not storing in Express for Node.js

Tags: node.js, express

I have the following route that basically acts on the post from a login form. The problem is that when the login is a success (member is found and the passwords match), the member._id is not stored in the session.

My route:

```
app.post('/signin', function(req, res) {
    Member.findOne({username: req.body.username}, function(error, member) {
        var matchPassword = crypto.createHmac('sha1', member.salt).update(req.body.password).digest('hex');
        if(member.password == matchPassword) {
            req.session.member_id = member._id;
            res.redirect('/' + member.username);
        }
    });
    res.redirect('/');
});
```

I get the following error in console when this route is fired:

```
node.js:134
        throw e; // process.nextTick error, or 'error' event on first tick
        ^
Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
    at ServerResponse.<anonymous> (http.js:527:11)
    at ServerResponse.setHeader (/Users/admin/Node Projects/sandboxProject/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/patch.js:62:20)
    at ServerResponse.header (/Users/admin/Node Projects/sandboxProject/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:280:8)
    at ServerResponse.redirect (/Users/admin/Node Projects/sandboxProject/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:413:10)
    at Promise.<anonymous> (/Users/admin/Node Projects/sandboxProject/app.js:109:8)
    at Promise.<anonymous> (/Users/admin/Node Projects/sandboxProject/node_modules/mongoose/lib/promise.js:120:8)
    at Promise.<anonymous> (events.js:64:17)
    at Promise.emit (/Users/admin/Node Projects/sandboxProject/node_modules/mongoose/lib/promise.js:59:38)
    at Promise.complete (/Users/admin/Node Projects/sandboxProject/node_modules/mongoose/lib/promise.js:70:20)
    at /Users/admin/Node Projects/sandboxProject/node_modules/mongoose/lib/query.js:1087:15
```

It would seem that it didn't like the "res.redirect('/' + member.username);" after the "req.session.member_id = member._id;". Is this because of the asynchronous nature of the Mongoose findOne callback that it's in? I've tried removing the res.redirect from the callback but the session data is not stored and when I leave it in there, I get the "headers already sent" error.

My configuration:

```
app.configure(function(){
    app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
    app.set('view engine', 'jade');
    app.use(express.cookieParser());
    app.use(express.session({ secret: "blahblah" }));
    app.use(express.bodyParser());
    app.use(express.methodOverride());
    app.use(app.router);
    app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
});
```

Comment: Have fixed the issue - turns out it was quite simple and required a little common sense!

As the callback from Mongoose was asynchronous and fired the session storage after the "res.redirect('/');" in my previous, broken version of the route. All you need to do is handle the failure inside the callback and drop the "res.redirect('/');" from the end of the route callback. Oops!

Comment: If a solution below worked, can you select one as the right answer so as to help others with the same problem?

Answer (score 8):

I had a similar problem. Although my problem was that when I deleted something from session, e.g. `delete req.session.user`, it would still be there after reloads and node app restarts. It would only be gone after `req.session.destroy()`.

I looked at Node's session [middleware docs](http://www.senchalabs.org/connect/middleware-session.html) and found that they have a `Session#save()` method. So I did `req.session.save()` after session object manipulations and it did fix my problem. Try it and see if it fixes yours.

Comment: Although this answer pointed me in the right direction I would be explicit about `req.session.save()` being an asynchronous function with callback as parameter. So anything that depends on the data upon save should be executed within the callback. This is usually not obvious when using just memory storage for development and actions happen "in-time."

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that `Member.findOne` is asynchronous. By the time its callback executes, the `res.redirect('/')` has already executed, which sets the appropriate HTTP response headers.  You can't send headers twice by HTTP rules, hence the error `Can't set headers after they are sent.`

You probably want to move the `redirect('/')` into an else block of your password matching.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem.
but my problem is at the time:

request.session.user = user;

I discovered through debug， When commenting out this line，This error does not occur：

// request.session.user = user;

this is my question:
[express 4.x session-mongoose Can't set headers after they are sent(Been resolved)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28058845/express-4-x-session-mongoose-cant-set-headers-after-they-are-sent)