# express 4.x session-mongoose Can't set headers after they are sent

Tags: javascript, node.js, session, express

node version v0.10.35;
express version v4.11.0;

My session is use session-mongoose save mongodb, but at the time:

```
request.session.user = user;
request.session.success = "sign in success!";
return response.redirect("/");


http.js:689
    throw new Error('Can\'t set headers after they are sent.');
Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
```

this is my code:

```
router.post("/signin", function (request, response) {
    var name = request.body.signinname;
    var pass = request.body.password;
    if(name == "" || pass == ""){
        request.session.error = "name and pass can not be empty!";
        return response.redirect("/signin");
    }
    User.get(name, function (error, usermodel) {
        if(!usermodel){
            request.session.error = "user does not exist!";
            return response.redirect("/signin");
        }
        if(usermodel.password != pass){
            request.session.error = "invalid password!";
            return response.redirect("/signin");
        }
        request.session.user = usermodel;
        request.session.success = "user sign in success!";
        response.redirect("/home");
    });
});
```

this is error log:

```
    http.js:689
    throw new Error('Can\'t set headers after they are sent.');
          ^
Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
    at ServerResponse.OutgoingMessage.setHeader (http.js:689:11)
    at ServerResponse.res.setHeader (d:\Develop\web\workspace\melove-timeline\node_modules\connect\lib\patch.js:134:22)
    at ServerResponse.header (d:\Develop\web\workspace\melove-timeline\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:695:10)
    at ServerResponse.send (d:\Develop\web\workspace\melove-timeline\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:146:12)
    at fn (d:\Develop\web\workspace\melove-timeline\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:929:10)
    at handleTemplate (d:\Develop\web\workspace\melove-timeline\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:209:18)
    at d:\Develop\web\workspace\melove-timeline\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:226:7
    at fs.js:271:14
    at Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
```

I discovered through debug， When commenting out this line，This error does not occur：

```
// request.session.user = user;
```

this is my node-modules version:

```
"dependencies": {
    "express": "~4.11.0",
    "mongoose": "~3.8.21",
    "body-parser": "~1.10.1",
    "cookie-parser": "~1.3.3",
    "express-session": "~1.10.1",
    "session-mongoose": "~0.5.2",
    "morgan": "~1.5.1",
    "debug": "~2.1.1",
    "ejs": "~2.1.4"
  }
```

and a question, at the time sign up save session is success:

```
router.post("/signup", function (request, response) {
    var lovecode = request.body.lovecode;
    var name = request.body.signinname;
    var pass = request.body.password;
    var confirmpass = request.body.confirmpassword;
    var email = request.body.email;

    if(name == "" || pass == "" || email == ""){
        request.session.error = "name pass email does not empty!";
        return response.redirect("/signup");
    }
    if(pass != confirmpass){
        request.session.error = "pass and confirmpass ";
        return response.redirect("/signup");
    }
    
    var user = new User({
        lovecode: lovecode,
        signinname: name,
        password: confirmpass,
        email: email
    });
    User.get(name, function (error, usermodel) {
        if(usermodel){
            request.session.error = "user already exist!";
            return response.redirect("/signup");
        }
        user.save(function (error, usermodel) { 
            if(error){
                request.session.error = error;
                return response.redirect("/signup");
            }
            request.session.user = user;
            request.session.success = "Sign up success!";
            response.redirect("/home");
        });
    });
});
```

this my user.js module code:

```
/**
 * Created by lzan13 on 2015/1/20.
 */
var mlmongodb = require("./mlmongodb.js");

var UserModel = mlmongodb.mongoose.model("Users");

function User(user){
    this.lovecode = user.lovecode;
    this.signinname = user.signinname;
    this.password = user.password;
    this.email = user.email;
}

User.prototype.save = function (callback) {
    var usermodel = new UserModel({
        signinname: this.signinname,
        password: this.password,
        email: this.email
    });
    usermodel.save(function (error, user) {
        if(error){
            return callback(error);
        }
        callback(null, user);
    });
}

User.get = function (name, callback) {
    UserModel.findOne({signinname: name}, function (error, user) {
        if(error){
            return callback(error);
        }
        callback(null, user);
    });
}

module.exports = User;
```

---

#### Resolved

session-mongoose save session to mongodb must object,

so this user.js module the function:

```
User.get = function (name, callback) {
    UserModel.findOne({signinname: name}, function (error, user) {
        if(error){
            return callback(error);
        }
        // this user must converted to objects
        var user = new User(user);
        callback(error, user);
    });
}
```

this user converted to objects!

Comment: What version of node and Express are you using?

Comment: Also what version of `express-session` is installed?

Comment: Node version is v0.10.35, express version is v4.11.0

Comment: OK, I solved this problem, Is session-mongoose save session to mongodb must object, so this the user.js module callback(error, user);Among the 'user' must Converted to objects;
var user = new User(user);
callback(error, user);